# MariaDB server dependent problem in group_concat when combined with group by

Tags: mysql, mariadb, group-concat

**more information added 2022-09-05.**

I have a problem with a sql query in a mariadb environment. I have a query that runs a number of tests in the database to identify unprocessed/unverified records, or records with contradicting data. The record identifiers that need to be checked are collected in one field (named fam_list) using a group_concat. The use of group_concat properly collects all record identifiers if no group by function is used. Issue is when group by is added in the query. I want to group the record identifiers by person responsible and project code. After adding the group by instruction, I retrieve several rows but the field that should collect all record identifiers is empty in all rows.

**Additionally surprising** is the fact that the column that counts the number of family identifiers (named fam_count), which is also an aggregate function, works correct in all attempts.
The query functions ok in my development machine, but fails in my production machine.

## **extra information 2022-09-05**

Removing parts of the query suggests that the origin of the problem lies in the combination of the table fam_proj_link and the view Team_curr_members.

Building up from left to right continues to produce the expected result until Team_curr_members is added in the join. From that moment onwards the group_concat column is empty. The table fam_proj_link can be joined with Team_curr_members directly. A query running in the table fam_proj_link joined to the view Team_curr_members still produces the empty group_concat column.

The simplified query that still fails is:

```
select 'uninsp' as checkname, l.proj_id, count(l.pb_fam_id), group_concat(l.pb_fam_id)
from PLS.fam_proj_link l left join Projects_2012.Team_curr_members t on(l.proj_id=t.proj_id and t.func_id=1)
where rank_id=-1
group by l.proj_id
```

I have tried modifying the join condition by doing a straight join, but still an empty group_concat field. I have tried redefyning the join to 'using(proj_id), but still an empty group_concat field.

In none of these cases does the mariadb server produce any error information and all the queries run as expected in the development server.

I checked the site for other usage of the group_concat function and found irregular behaviour in more pages. Including pages that used to work correctly until shortly before my holidays.

I have run optimize tables on the entire database and restarted the mariadb server package, but without improvement.

Could it be that there are damages in some database related files and if so, where do I have to look and what do I have to look for?

## end of extra added information

**Does anybody have any idea what could be the reason or what I can try to find out what goes wrong?**

Query (for one of the tests):
This works in development and production:

```
  select 'uninsp' as checkname, coalesce(user_id,0) as user_id, coalesce(firstsur,' none') as firstsur, l.proj_id, label, stat_name, stat_class, count(distinct pb_fam_id) as fam_count, group_concat(distinct pb_fam_id) as fam_list
  from PLS.fam_proj_link l join Projects_2012.Proj_list_2018 p using(proj_id) join Projects_2012.Proj_status_reflist using(stat_id)
  left join Projects_2012.Team_curr_members t on(p.proj_id=t.proj_id and t.func_id=1) left join UserData.people_view using(user_id)
  where ref_code and stat_name!='cancelled' and rank_id=-1;
```

This works in development only, not in production:

```
  select 'uninsp' as checkname, coalesce(user_id,0) as user_id, coalesce(firstsur,' none') as firstsur, l.proj_id, label, stat_name, stat_class, count(distinct pb_fam_id) as fam_count, group_concat(distinct pb_fam_id) as fam_list
  from PLS.fam_proj_link l join Projects_2012.Proj_list_2018 p using(proj_id) join Projects_2012.Proj_status_reflist using(stat_id)
  left join Projects_2012.Team_curr_members t on(p.proj_id=t.proj_id and t.func_id=1) left join UserData.people_view using(user_id)
  where ref_code and stat_name!='cancelled' and rank_id=-1
  group by user_id, proj_id;
```

Production machine:
Debian linux running mariadb 10.1.41

Development machine:
Manjaro linux running mariadb 10.8.3

Of course, I can solve the issue by abandoning the group_concat in mariadb and store the record identifiers in arrays in php and implode the array before generating the output, but I assume that concatenation in mariadb is faster than concatenation via arrays in php.

Relevant table definitions:
fam_proj_link

```
--
-- Table structure for table `fam_proj_link`
--

CREATE TABLE `fam_proj_link` (
  `proj_id` smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `pb_fam_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `originator` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `rank_id` tinyint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
  `factsheet` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `cust_title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- RELATIONS FOR TABLE `fam_proj_link`:
--   `rank_id`
--       `def_ranks` -> `rank_id`
--   `pb_fam_id`
--       `pb_fams` -> `pb_fam_id`
--   `proj_id`
--       `Projects` -> `proj_id`
--

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `fam_proj_link`
--
ALTER TABLE `fam_proj_link`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`proj_id`,`pb_fam_id`) USING BTREE,
  ADD KEY `originator` (`originator`),
  ADD KEY `rank_id` (`rank_id`),
  ADD KEY `pb_fam_id` (`pb_fam_id`),
  ADD KEY `factsheet` (`factsheet`);

--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `fam_proj_link`
--
ALTER TABLE `fam_proj_link`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fam_proj_link_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`rank_id`) REFERENCES `def_ranks` (`rank_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fam_proj_link_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`pb_fam_id`) REFERENCES `pb_fams` (`pb_fam_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fam_proj_link_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`proj_id`) REFERENCES `Projects_2012`.`Projects` (`proj_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Proj_list_2018 is a view with the below stand-in structure:
all fields are indexed in the parent tables, except for the label which is a combination of a group_concat and a normal concat over fields in three different tables.

```
--
-- Stand-in structure for view `Proj_list_2018`
-- (See below for the actual view)
--
CREATE TABLE `Proj_list_2018` (
`proj_id` smallint(6) unsigned
,`priority` tinyint(4)
,`stat_id` tinyint(4) unsigned
,`ref_code` bigint(20)
,`label` mediumtext
);
```

Proj_status_reflist:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `Proj_status_reflist`
--

CREATE TABLE `Proj_status_reflist` (
  `stat_id` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `stat_group_id` tinyint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `stat_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-',
  `stat_class` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- RELATIONS FOR TABLE `Proj_status_reflist`:
--   `stat_group_id`
--       `Proj_status_groups` -> `stat_group_id`
--

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `Proj_status_reflist`
--
ALTER TABLE `Proj_status_reflist`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`stat_id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `stat_name_UNIQUE` (`stat_name`),
  ADD KEY `stat_group_id` (`stat_group_id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `Proj_status_reflist`
--
ALTER TABLE `Proj_status_reflist`
  MODIFY `stat_id` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `Proj_status_reflist`
--
ALTER TABLE `Proj_status_reflist`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `Proj_status_reflist_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`stat_group_id`) REFERENCES `Proj_status_groups` (`stat_group_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Team_curr_members is a view with the below stand-in structure:
all fields are indexed in the parent table.

```
--
-- Stand-in structure for view `Team_curr_members`
-- (See below for the actual view)
--
CREATE TABLE `Team_curr_members` (
`proj_id` smallint(5) unsigned
,`func_id` tinyint(3) unsigned
,`user_id` smallint(5) unsigned
);
```

people_view is a view with the below stand-in structure:

```
--
-- Stand-in structure for view `people_view`
-- (See below for the actual view)
--
CREATE TABLE `people_view` (
`user_id` smallint(5) unsigned
,`synth_empl` int(1)
,`firstsur` varchar(77)
,`surfirst` varchar(78)
);
```

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056 for SQL related questions. Add sample data to your question, the result you get with your question and the actual result you are currently getting.

Comment: See if this helps:  https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/316483/1876

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying many things, I noticed that the problem appeared in more group_concat queries, many of them had been running without problems for several years. Rebuilding the indexes of the database tables did not solve the issue. Since the software was not altered during the last three years, I concluded that the database engine might be damaged.
I asked IT to create a new virtual server. After building a complete new server environment and migration of the databases and web interface to the new server all problems were solved.

Apparently the problem was not in the queries, but in the server enviroment. I have not discovered which part of the old server environment caused the actual issue, but possibly one or more mariadb/php related files were damaged.

Thanks to those that took the effort to come with suggestions.